# Translate formula into Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

can anybody assist me in implementing the following formula into excel:

Comment: I'd put all the values into named cells and use those in my formulas. That will simplify the process significantly.

Comment: You can generalise it into 2 formulas, one for even rows and one for odd rows (apart from the first row which is a constant), so with some effort you could get a single formula which you could pull down. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi! Yes I assigned TP, RL etc to Cells but I am struggling with the formula for L1-L10.

Comment: Well I managed to calcualte L2 and L3. My formulas always stopped working for L4 to L10. Since you have changes in signs and multiplication byTPR1 and TPR2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was thinking of

```
=IF(ISEVEN(ROW()),ABS(SUM(IF(ISODD(ROW(H$39:H39)),-TP,TTPR1)*H$39:H39))/(TTPR1-PPO),
ABS(SUM(IF(ISODD(ROW(H$39:H39)),TP,-TTPR2)*H$39:H39))/(TP-PPO))
```

to be entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Oh great thank you! Do you think it is also possible to implement this using a formula without array/matrix. I am not quite into this type of excel formulas

Comment: I can't think of another way of doing without writing out a lot of separate formulas. IMO it is worth learning the basics of array formulas because they are very useful in this sort of situation. Another way to go (since I notice you've done some before) would be to write it in VBA - probably quite a short piece of code.

Comment: OK thank you for your support! great job :-) I will look into arrays then in Excel